# Spring Security возвращает ошибку 405 Request Method 'POST' Not Supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Я использую Spring Security и Spring MVC в своем проекте, и я пытаюсь сделать страницу авторизации, но, к сожалению, при нажатии на кнопку "Log in", появляется сообщение с ошибкой 405.

Версия Spring: 5.1.9.RELEASE

thymeleaf login html файл:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Custom Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Custom Login Page</h2>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="POST">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Security Configuration файл:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public WebSecurityConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .successForwardUrl("/index")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureForwardUrl("/error")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("jim").password(passwordEncoder().encode("12345")).roles("ADMIN").and()
            .withUser("bob").password(passwordEncoder().encode("67890")).roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Controller файл:

```java
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView userIndex() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("user/index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminIndex() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("admin/index");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loginPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView login(Authentication authentication) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        String userName = userDetails.getUsername();
        String password = userDetails.getPassword();
        if (userName.equals("jim") && password.equals("12345")) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("index");
        } else {
            modelAndView.setViewName("error");
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я упускаю? Заранее большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: https://github.com/Antonio112009/HibernateAnnotationsExamples рассмотрите данный пример проектв

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал бы все `RequestMapping` в отдельный файл записывать. А то все в кучу в одном файле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас "заблокирован" `login`. т.е. доступ к данной странице можно лишь получить тогда, когда авторизуетесь. Отсюда вам следует `login`-страницу сделать  публичным:

```java
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/registration", "/change/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()


                    .and().formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .failureUrl("/error")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .passwordParameter("password")


                    .and().logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")


                    .and().exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
        }
```

Comment: Страница для ввода логина и пароля загружается. Ошибка возникает именно после нажатия на кнопку "Log in". Причем совершенно недавно я заметил, что если ввести данные пользователей из файла Security Configuration, то появляется ошибка 405, но становится возможным переходить по всем страницам, которые есть у меня в проекте, а если ввести неправильные данные пользователя, то появляется ошибка 404, и доступна только страница для ввода логина и пароля

Comment: @Дмитрий Опробуйте настройки, которые я вам предложил)

Comment: @Дмитрий Кстати, csrf  не обязательно вручную добавлять. Спринг делает это автоматически, так что данную строчку можно убрать

Comment: вместо `id="username" name="username"` - используйте `th:field="username"`. th:field автоматически генерирует id и name

Comment: я ошибся ссылкой... Вот что вам надо было посмотреть - https://github.com/Antonio112009/HibernateAuthenticationExample

Comment: @Дмитрий как вы смогли решить проблему? Мне это нужно для редактирования своего ответа под вашу проблему

Comment: Я просто посмотрел код на github, который Вы мне прислали, сделал изменения под себя, и все заработало, а потом обнаружил, что изменения, которые я внес, практически ничем не отличаются от Вашего ответа, поэтому я отметил его галочкой. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете Security, но между тем пишите сами логику аутентификации. Зачем?

`.loginPage("/login")` устанавливает начальную страницу с формой аутентификации. 
`"/login"` - этим путем замапен контроллер самого спринга, который осуществляет аутентификацию. Лучше изменить его на другой (например так: `.loginPage("/auth")`, и изменить путь в контроллере `loginPage()`. Свой контроллер `login()` уберите.